# Remove several lines from the top of a traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback, python-importlib

I am calling `importlib.import_module("somemodulename")` to import some customized user defined module. This import may fail. I want to give the user the information about why it failed so I need to print the traceback but it tends to be very long full of lines from `importlib` module. For example it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\abc\cde\efg\importer.py", line 101, in load
    self.__module = importlib.import_module(self.__name)
  File "C:\Programming\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\abc\cde\efg\modules\testerror.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = 1 / 0  # intentional error for module testing purposes
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Obviously most of the lines are of no interest to the user. I want the traceback to look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\abc\cde\efg\modules\testerror.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = 1 / 0  # intentional error for module testing purposes
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But the problem is that I cannot rely on the number of rows generated from the `importlib` package (this is an implementation detail which may be changed in future versions, may be platform or Python installation specific), which I want to skip, neither on the number of rows generated by the custom module error (he can import some other modules on his own, which may cause the error), which I want to keep. To complicate it further, the user can also call `importlib` module function, which is fine in that case and should be included in the traceback.

In other words, I need to get rid of all the first block of `importlib` error lines from the traceback. Any ideas other than parsing the traceback lines in some 'clever' way, which I think would be a hackish and very fragile solution relying on too many implementation details from the `importlib` package?

Note: I am using Python 3.5+, the solution should be platform agnostic

Comment: Have a look at the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I dug deeper into the `traceback` and `importlib` modules and I think I have found the solution. This seems to work fine for modules in normal Python files. Not sure however about frozen packages, zipped packages etc. Needs more testing for these scenarios.

```
import importlib
import sys
import traceback

moduleName = "somepackage.somemodule"
try:
   importlib.import_module(moduleName)
except Exception:
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(moduleToImport)
    if spec is None:
        # if the module is not found, then do not print traceback at all
        count = 0
    else:
        fileName = spec.loader.get_filename()
        extracts = traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
        count = len(extracts)
        # find the first occurrence of the module file name
        for i, extract in enumerate(extracts):
            if extract[0] == fileName:
                break
            count -= 1
    # keep only the count of last lines
    print(traceback.format_exc(limit=-count))
```